# как сделать так что несмотря на input() программа продолжала работать ?Python

Tags: python

мне нужно сделать так чтобы несмотря на input() программа не останавливалась и продолжала работать
как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще `input()` *"останавливает"* программу, ожидая ввод данных и если дальнейшие действия программы зависит от этих самых **введенных данных**, то скорее всего невозможно будет обеспечить дальнейшую правильную работу программы.

---

Но если допустим у вас есть функционал, не зависящий от **введенных данных**, можно вынести его в **отдельный поток** ([threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)) или использовать **асинхронность** ([asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)).